# Pandas: Multiple rows of a data frame into a single cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to merge multiple rows of a dataframe into a single Cell, I already tried multiple ways to  merge the required input into output format but couldn't able to succeed. below is my input format and desired out put format any help is much Appreciated!

Input Data

[image: Input Data]

Desired Output Data

[image: Desired Output Data]

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"Text1": ["1_1"    , "1_1"  , "1_1"      , "1_2"      , "1_2"          , "1-3"    , "1-3"  , "1-3"      , "", "1-4"      , "1-4"          ],
                     "Text2": ["HI"     , "HI"   , "HI"       , "Hello"    , "Hello"        , "Hiiii"  , ""     , ""         , "How are You?" , "Hellooo"   , ""],
                     "Text3": ["welcome", "Howdy", "greetings", "good day.", "good morning.", "welcome", "Howdy", "greetings", ""             , "good day.", "good morning."],
                     "Text4": ["S11"    , "S11"  , "S11"      , "S12"      , "S12"          , "S12"    , "S13"  , "S13"      , ""             , "S14"      , "S14"          ]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Text1', 'Text2','Text4', 'Text4']) 

print(df)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data in text format.

Comment: I will provide data in text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward fill the `Text1` column first to replace the blanks, then group by that column and aggregate the other column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Text1": ["HI", "HI", "HI", "Hello", "Hello", "Hiiii", "", "", "How are You?", "Hellooo", ""],
                   "Text2": ["welcome", "Howdy", "greetings", "good day.", "good morning.", "welcome", "Howdy", "greetings", "", "good day.", "good morning."]})
result = df.groupby(df["Text1"].replace("", np.nan).ffill()).agg({"Text2": "/".join})
```

Comment: Hi @Stuart Thanks for Your Solution. But when I am working with actual data It is getting an Error
I posted the actual Data, Please have a look

Comment: @thrinadhn I think this is because you have changed the labels - just ensure `Text1` contains the labels and `Text2` contains the text to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
df['Text2'] = df[['Text1','Text2']].groupby(['Text1'])['Text2'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df[['Text1','Text2']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: I think you just need to drop duplicates